# Paginar tabla html m

Tags: html, c#, sql, linq, razor

Realizar una paginación (tres por página) de los elementos resultantes de una consulta linq :

```
       var list = from PEL_T_Prestamo in dbDatos.PEL_T_Prestamo
                           join PEL_T_Peliculas in dbDatos.PEL_T_Peliculas
                            on PEL_T_Prestamo.idpelicula equals PEL_T_Peliculas.idPelicula
                           where dateCheckec == PEL_T_Prestamo.FechaPrestamo
                           select new { PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo,PEL_T_Prestamo.FechaPrestamo,PEL_T_Prestamo.FechaDevolucion, PEL_T_Prestamo.DiasPrestamoEfectuado};
```

presentados mediante una tabla html. Se ha de realizar mediante dos botones de tipo input.

Por ahora este es el código:

```
                    if (list.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <p>No se han encontrado coincidencias con los criterios de búsqueda especificados</p>
                }
                else
                {

                    <table>

                        <thead>

                            <tr>

                                <th>Título</th>
                                <th>Fecha préstamo</th>
                                <th>Fecha devolución</th>
                                <th>Días préstamo</th>

                            </tr>

                        </thead>


                            @foreach (var elements in list)
                            {
                                <tr><td>@elements.Titulo</td><td>@elements.FechaPrestamo</td><td>@elements.FechaDevolucion</td><td>@elements.DiasPrestamoEfectuado</td></tr>
                            }


                        }

                    </table>



                    <input id="siguiente" type="submit" value="Anterior" />

                    <input id="anterior" type="submit" value="Siguiente" />
                }
            }
```

No sé cómo controlar cuando se ha pulsado uno de los botones input, como controlar la páginación, ni tampoco como no perder la información del registro actual a la hora de paginar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No puedo hacer el uso de Forms o mvc debido a que es un ejercicio educativo.

Answer (score 0):

Para pagina con linq se usa el `Take()` y `Skip()`

[How To Implement Paging Using Skip And Take Operators In LINQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-paging-using-skip-and-take-operators-in-linq/)

Teniendo el linq podrias usar

```
int pageNumber = 1;
int pageSize = 10;

var list = from PEL_T_Prestamo in dbDatos.PEL_T_Prestamovar 
             ....;

var listPaging = list.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Aqui tomas paginas de 10 elementos, tomando la primer pagina
Se supone que debes conocer cuantas paginas vas a tener conociendo el total, para eso usas

```
 var countPages = list.Count() / pageSize;
```

Comment: ¿cómo podría controlar que se mostrara la primera página y posteriormente el número de registros deseados por página al pusar el input? mi mayor duda es no poder controlar los elementos dentro de "list".

Comment: Lo controlas definiendo html que muestre los numeros del paginado, no se a que input haces referencia pero no se usa ninguno, la lista devuelve los registros de la pagina que se solicita visualizar, pero es la UI quien envia estos datos ya sea cuando carga o cuando se presiona el link que envia una nueva pagina. Pero eno tiene ningun html que este armando el paginado

Comment: Analiza https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp veras como se generan los numeros que representa cada pagina, en este caso se usa bootstrap, pero se podria hacer usando solo html y css https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pagination.asp

Comment: He adjuntado una foto con el formato.

Comment: en las flechas vas a tener que mentener el valor de la pagina actual y conocer cuentas paginas puedes generar con los datos que tienes. De esta forma cuando la pagina actual llega a a cantidad maxima de paginas deberias inhabilitar la flecha para no continuar pulsandola